# Optimal order to traverse a grid with caching

Tags: algorithms, cache

Let's say I want to evaluate a two-argument function using all possible combinations of elements from sets A and B as arguments.

For example, if the function is addition, we get this grid:

```
       A

     1 2 3 
   1 2 3 4
B  2 3 4 5
   3 4 5 6
```

Let's also say that retrieving an element from a set is has a fixed cost, but we can remember up to N elements at a time.

Is there a known optimal order in which to consider the elements, in terms of cost?

For example, we could start with the first element of A, then consider every element of B. If the size of B is much larger than N then every new element of B will be a "cache miss", making this a not very efficient strategy.

Comment: I didn't prove this, but it seems that processing in squares of sizes $\frac N2 \times \frac N 2$ should be optimal.

Comment: (@Dmitry: making that recursive looks a promising strategy for multi-level hierarchies. But what about the "far from square shapes" chpatrick expressed concern about?)

Comment: Do you plan to keep *all* results, "column" or "row summaries", or just one summary information?

Comment: @greybeard For the diagram above I would like to keep column summaries, specifically the minimum value for each A.

Comment: Please edit information that enables more helpful answers right into the question body. Such questions led to research of *cache conscious* implementations as well as *data structures&algorithms*, taking into account knowledge about cache sizes and strategies. Uneasiness with the need to obtain such knowledge at run-time, if not earlier, led to interest in "*cache oblivious*" processing programming (*cache conscious, detail oblivious*, really).